# Adding detailled costs in osm2po

Tags: osm2po

I want to improve my bike routing. I know, that I can change the "costs" by changing the speed in the config file, but for me it's not detailed enough. A small subset of my config file looks like that:

```
wtr.tag.highway.track =          2,  71, 10,  bike
wtr.tag.tracktype.grade1 =       1,  81, 15, bike
```

What I wish to do is, that a `highway=track` which has ALSO the `tracktype=grade1` as tag gets a higher speed (here 15) than a street, which is "only" declared as track (here 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. But please download v5.0.70 (Latest Snapshot) because prior versions might have a little bug here.
Try sth. like this:

```
wayTagResolver.prefix=btr
btr.flagList=bike,track,grade
btr.finalMask=bike|track&grade

btr.tag.highway.cycleway=2,1,15,bike
btr.tag.highway.track=2,2,10,track
btr.tag.tracktype.grade[4|5]=1,3,20,grade
```

The trick is to handle tracktype as main tag and give it a higher priority. New is the finalMask syntax saying that either "bike" or "grade + track" are allowed but not "grade" alone.
I hope, this gives you an idea of how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you Carsten. It seems to be enough for my purposes.